# Highlight segments on slider bar

Tags: c#, wpf, slider, progress-bar

I am looking a way to highlight segments (in yellow) on a slider/progress bar like this:

[image: slider with highlighted segments example]

I found some article discuss how to build customized WPF slider control by using style:

- http://codingsense.wordpress.com/2010/02/01/customize-a-slider-in-wpf-step-by-step-tutorial/
- http://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/06/12/wpf-control-templating/
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36802/WPF-Colour-Slider

But what I need is to highlight given segments on the slider bar programmatically.

For example:

```
//Given:

List<Rectangle> rectangles; 

//And invoke

mycontrol.highlight(rectangles);
```

How could I do this? Or more specifically, how could I draw on the slider bar at runtime?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10086930/1569

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*in slider*
Property **IsSelectionRangeEnabled**

> If true, you can use a selection range to shade in a portion of the
>   slider bar. You set the position selection range using the
>   SelectionStart and SelectionEnd properties. The selection range
>   has no intrinsic meaning, but you can use it for whatever purpose
>   makes sense. For example, media players sometimes use a shaded
>   background bar to indicate the download progress for a media file.

Comment: I had check it out it can support only one selection range,how can I make it to multiple selection range ?

Comment: unfortunately in slider and progressbar only one selection range

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found a way to workaround: place this slider bar on canvas, then draw to this canvas.

Comment: @DuSijun it would help if you can show an example to help others along the way.