# Slider with multiple intervals

Tags: wpf, slider

Currently, the WPF slider has some properties that allow defining and viewing **a single  interval** on a slider: SelectionStart, SelectionEnd and IsSelectionRangeEnabled.

By setting these values

```
<Slider Minimum="0" Maximum="300" Value="150" IsSelectionRangeEnabled="True" SelectionStart="50" SelectionEnd="200"/>
```

you get the selected interval in the slider, colored in blue, like this:

[image]

What I would like to do is to be able to define **multiple intervals** - e.g. (50-100), (110-130), (170-200) and (210-240), which would look like this:

[image]

Any ideas on how to aproach this issue or what template I should try modifying in order to get this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this may not be an answer but a workaround. I place slider bar on canvas, then draw to canvas [Highlight segments on slider bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555955/highlight-segments-on-slider-bar)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Ticks property to set multiple intervals. Im not sure exactly how you wanted it to work from your explaination above, but here is an example.

```
<Slider Minimum="0" Maximum="300" Value="150" 
IsSelectionRangeEnabled="True" SelectionStart="50" 
SelectionEnd="200" IsMoveToPointEnabled="True" 
TickPlacement="BottomRight" Ticks="50, 100, 105, 140, 150, 200" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" />
```

Comment: Ticks doesn't help me. I edited my question and I hope it's easier to understand now.